# Vertx instance variable is null in Spring context

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vert.x

I defined a Spring Boot App as a Verticle as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringAppVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {


private Vertx myVertx;

@Override
public void start() {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringAppVerticle.class);
    System.out.println("SpringAppVerticle started!");
    this.myVertx = vertx;
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/hello")
public class RequestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public void getEcho() {
        JsonObject message = new JsonObject()
                .put("text", "Hello world!");
        myVertx.eventBus().send(EchoServiceVerticle.ADDRESS, message, reply -> {
            JsonObject replyBody = (JsonObject) reply.result().body();
            System.out.println(replyBody.encodePrettily());
        });
    }

}
}
```

I have a second non-Spring Verticle that is basically a echo service:

```
public class EchoServiceVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

public static final String ADDRESS = "echo-service";

@Override
public void start() {
    System.out.println("EchoServiceVerticle started!");
    vertx.eventBus().consumer(EchoServiceVerticle.ADDRESS, message -> {
        System.out.println("message received");
        JsonObject messageBody = (JsonObject) message.body();
        messageBody.put("passedThrough", "echo-service");
        message.reply(messageBody);
    });
}

}
```

The problem is that I get a nullpointer at line myVertx.eventbus().send in SpringAppVerticle class as the myVertx variable is null.

How do I properly instantiate a Vertx variable in a Spring context in order that I can exchange message between my both verticles?

My project can be found here: https://github.com/r-winkler/vertx-spring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the exception is the following:

SpringAppVerticle bean that is created during spring init is another object than starts the spring boot application. So you have two objects, one that has `start()` method invoked and another one that doesn't. Second one actually handles requests. So what you need is to register verticles as spring beans.

For samples of vertx/spring interoperability please refer to [vertx examples repo](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples).

P.S. I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/r-winkler/vertx-spring/pull/1) to your repo to make your example work.

Comment: Thank you, that is nice. However, now both verticles are using Spring. Actually, I wanted to setup a Spring verticle communicating with a non-Spring verticle. Maybe I  manage to get that by myself now.

Comment: You can use eventbus in vertx cluster.  Check vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#event_bus for some more info.